# Unaligned read : memcpy generates better code than shift

Tags: c++, memcpy, shift

I was writing some function to read 2,4,8 bytes from a unaligned byte array:

I had 2 versions.

1: access byte by byte and then shift

```
template <typename T, size_t val = sizeof(T)>
struct ExtractValue {
    // for non pointer types
    static T get (const uint8_t  *p)
    {
        return (ExtractValue<T, val - 1>::get(p) << 8) |
                static_cast<T>(p[val - 1]);
    }
};

// ignore, Just to terminate the above template recursion
template <typename T>
struct ExtractValue<T, 0> {
    static T get (const uint8_t *p)
    {
        return 0;
    }
};
```

version 2: use memcpy:

```
template <typename T>
struct ExtractValueI<T, 4> {
    static T get (const uint8_t *p)
    {
        T t;
        memcpy(&t, p, sizeof(T));
        return __builtin_bswap32(t);
    }
};
```

Looking at the assembly code generated. Actually the memcpy version has much less instructions - 40% less instruction than the shift version. The memcpy seems to faster? So is the second approach the best always?

Comment: Did you consider the fact that `memcpy` is part of the standard library and probably not inlined? That means it's actual code is hidden away and doesn't affect your measured code size.

Comment: @BenSteffan - On the contrary, it may be a compiler intrinsic and lead to heavily optimised code.

Comment: I'd imagine that the use of a compiler intrinsic (`__builtin_bswap32`) is definitely helping here...

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth May, or may not. Until we know what compiler and what flags OP used, it's really anyone's guess.

Comment: @Ben Steffan the `memcpy` is inlined. It reduces to just one instruction for a 4byte access a single `movl`. __builtin_bswap32 is just one instruction `bswap`. This is with g++ 4.9 on 64bit intel (sandy bridge) with `O2` optimization

Comment: See what happens when you make `ExtractValue::get` static in the base specialization.

Comment: @Christopher Oicles It was actually a `static`. copy paste error corrected it.

Comment: These do different things depending on what T is , so you can't really compare them

Comment: From what I see you want to read the byte sequence as big endian integer. The second version assumes that the integer `T t` is little endian, which is not true for some platforms.

Comment: @dimm yeah for big endian processors , we can hide the bswap behind a macro.